# Query still running for django_migrations

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-database, django-deployment

I'm developing a django web app and i have notice something strange.
The following query will stay in execution in the DB

> SELECT "django_migrations"."app", "django_migrations"."name" FROM "django_migrations"

here the example from: select query_start,state_change,waiting,state,query from pg_stat_activity;

```
test6=> select query_start,state_change,waiting,state,query from pg_stat_activity;
          query_start          |         state_change          | waiting | state  |                                                                  query
-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2017-06-21 16:02:21.926337+02 | 2017-06-21 16:02:21.926402+02 | f       | idle   | SELECT "django_migrations"."app", "django_migrations"."name" FROM "django_migrations"
```

untill stop the "runserver"

Current settings:

- Django 1.11.2
- PostgreSQL 9.2.17
- Using Django ORM only
- All migrations were applied
- CONN_MAX_AGE setted in settings.py

Why Django doesn't close the connection after the query execution?

Comment: What do you mean, the query is still running? How are you determining that? How are you running it in the first place?

Comment: via "pg_stat_activity". The query still in "idle" status and the connection still alive after 10/15 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#persistent-connections), Django uses persistent connections:

> [...] each thread maintains its own connection

The `runserver` command is itself a thread, and the `SELECT "django_migrations"."app", "django_migrations"."name" FROM "django_migrations"` simply represent the last query made on the connection, once the results has been returned, the state is left idle.

If you try to execute a query once migrations are checked, in wsgi for example, that request would replace the one you are seeing.

**Hence**, the runserver by default create a thread for each incoming request, so the connection made (in main thread) for checking migrations is never closed, by the doc:

> At the beginning of each request, Django closes the connection if it
>   has reached its maximum age. If your database terminates idle
>   connections after some time, you should set CONN_MAX_AGE to a lower
>   value, so that Django doesn’t attempt to use a connection that has
>   been terminated by the database server. (This problem may only affect
>   very low traffic sites.)

As you can read, the closing is made either by Postgres, or by Django on the next request. So either you configure postgres to kill the idle connections, or you can use the `--nothreading` on runserver to reuse the connection made by the main thread (warning: it highly affects performance).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but why if i set the 'CONN_MAX_AGE' to 5 seconds the connection still open?

Comment: I added the part and the explanation as to why the first connection is kept with runserver

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i probably misunderstand how CONN_MAX_AGE works. i will probably use `from django.db import close_old_connections
close_old_connections()` for manage the automatic close of the connection with an automatic task. Thanks